# how to cm.save() before ZeroClipboard action?

Tags: javascript, codemirror, zeroclipboard

Hi i am using codemirror,  but how to used copy data to clipbord from textarea using codemirror or Where to use cm.save() before ZeroClipboard action?

```
<button class="copy" id="copy" data-clipboard-target="data_codemirror">Copy</button>
<textarea  id="data_codemirror"></textarea>

<script>
   var clientTarget = new ZeroClipboard( $("#copybuttonindex"), {
       moviePath: "cssjs/ZeroClipboard.swf",
       debug: false
   });
</script>
```